# CSS Only: Li Equal Height >IE10+Edge

Tags: html, css

has someone a CSS-only solution to make the content (`<a>`) of an `<li>` equal height as the `<li>` itself - and the `<li>` equal height as the parent (`<nav>`)?

The "Filter"-Button should be 100% height of the `<nav>`

See it in action:
http://jsbin.com/qalufokimo/

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 300;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.filter h2,
.filter h3 {
  color: white;
}

.filter {
  background-color: #19679e;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
}

.filter a,
.filter label {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filter ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.filter.dropdown form {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #19679e;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

.filter.dropdown nav {
  height: 100%;
}

.filter.dropdown nav>ul {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-collapse: separate;
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
}

.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li {
  display: block;
  display: table-column;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .filter.dropdown nav>ul>li {
    float: none;
  }
}

.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:first-child {
  float: none;
  margin-right: 24px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:first-child {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:first-child>a:focus {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:first-child>a:focus+form {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:first-child a {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #4785b1;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:first-child a {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:first-child a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #19679e;
}

.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:first-child a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:first-child a [class^="icon-"],
.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:first-child a [class*=" icon-"] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: calc(50% - 7px);
  margin-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:first-child a [class^="icon-"],
  .filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:first-child a [class*=" icon-"] {
    position: unset;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
}

.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:not(:first-child) {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:not(:first-child) {
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
  }
}

.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:not(:first-child) a {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  background-color: #4785b1;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 24px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:not(:first-child) a span:first-child {
  max-width: 16em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  float: left;
}

.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:not(:first-child) a [class="icon-"],
.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:not(:first-child) a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:not(:first-child) a [class="icon-"] [class^="icon-"],
.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:not(:first-child) a [class="icon-"] [class*=" icon-"],
.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:not(:first-child) a:hover [class^="icon-"],
.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:not(:first-child) a:hover [class*=" icon-"] {
  color: #19679e;
}

.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:not(:first-child) a [class^="icon-"],
.filter.dropdown nav>ul>li:not(:first-child) a [class*=" icon-"] {
  top: 1px;
  right: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 7px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="filter dropdown">
  <nav class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Filter
                            <span class="icon-chevron-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"><!-- --></span>
                            </a>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="" method="post" action="" class="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h3>Channels</h3>
                <ul class="row" role="menu">
                  <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkbox-widget list-field" name="channel:list" id="channel-1">
                    <label for="channel-1"><span class="label">Channel 1</span></label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3 class="sr-only">Ausgewählte Filter</h3>
        <a href=""><span>Lorem ipsum</span> <span class="sr-only">- remove filter,</span><span class="icon-chevron-right glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"><!-- --></span></a>
        <a href=""><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span> <span class="sr-only">- remove filter,</span><span class="icon-chevron-right glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"><!-- --></span></a>
        <a href=""><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</span> <span class="sr-only">- remove filter,</span><span class="icon-chevron-right glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"><!-- --></span></a>
        <a href=""><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tortor nisi, suscipit</span> <span class="sr-only">- remove filter,</span><span class="icon-chevron-right glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"><!-- --></span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>

<p>fasfalsfjj fj asdf</p>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Could you be more specific? Is it the 'filter' button?

Comment: Don't just paste all your code, make a [MCVE].  Also which anchor are you talking about?

Comment: I mean both `<li>` should always be the same height. Chrome/FF working perfect. The "Filter" Button should be the same height as the selected Filters...

Comment: The filter button doesn't have the same height as the selected filters for me (Chrome). But maybe I just don't get it

Comment: “Equal height” these days screams _flexbox_. And basic support in IE 10 should be good enough for this.

Comment: I wonder if you expect other people to be able to read this CSS?  Because they can't.